# AWS CDK: How to pass build_args to DockerImageCode.from_image_asset

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have a Dockerfile in the project which, during build of an image, needs to pull something from a private GitHub repository. Hence I need to pass it a GitHub token. Building this way locally is all fine.

However I need to achieve this in `CodePipeline` in `cdk` to deploy a `Lambda`. So in one of the stacks I use:

```
DockerImageFunction(self, "SomeId",
  code=DockerImageCode.from_image_asset(
    directory='some-dir',
    build_args={
      "GITHUB_TOKEN": aws_cdk.core.SecretValue.secrets_manager('github-token').to_string(),
    },
  )
)
```

([see API reference here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/DockerImageCode.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_image_asset))

This gives me an error:

> jsii.errors.JSIIError: Cannot use tokens in keys or values of "buildArgs" since they are needed before deployment

Also the linked reference says:

> Since Docker build arguments are resolved before deployment, keys and values cannot refer to unresolved tokens

In such a case, how do I pass in the github token to Docker build which is stored in the secret manager in aws account?

Comment: Do you use the CDK to create the secret? If you don't, than you could use the *S*DK, during your CDK build, to fetch the value of the secret.

Comment: I'll write an answer if it will help.

Comment: @user17242583 I think I have run into [this open issue sadly](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14395). However feel free to write an alternative if you want.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work you have to have the token present during synthesis time (as you correctly mention). A good practice is to have these tokens provided by your CI/CD as environment variables during your builds.

For CodeBuild you can specify the variables in the console; a variable can be internally stored in SecretsManager. More [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_EnvironmentVariable.html) and [on this blog](https://blog.shikisoft.com/define-environment-vars-aws-codebuild-buildspec/).

Hope this helps a little